# PHP: sorting out in a smart coding way?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, filtering

So i have this videosection, but i want to make a "sorting" option avaible for users.

Sorting Options: ALL (no WHERE in the sql statement), Videoklips (WHERE SCtry = 0), SC try (WHERE SCtry = 1)

Now, i know how to do it "my" way. I would have placed links on index.php:
`?sort=video` and `?sort=SCtry`

Then make 2, if sort video, if sort sctry 
and then duplicate the whole index.php right now(which displays everything) into the 2 if's and then just edit the SQL statement SELECT, with WHERE SCtry = '0' on ?sort=video, and WHERE SCtry = '1' on ?sort=SCtry.

Now, i KNOW how to sort out, but i want to code it in a smarter way (if it exists, of course), because this seems to be too much to duplicate the whole site and then just only change 1 line...

Example of what i ment with index.php, that i am going to duplicate:

```
<?php 
$hent_meetup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member_film ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,200") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($vis = mysql_Fetch_array($hent_meetup)) { 
?>
```

Comment: A few questions: You are not using the smarty templating engine, are you? If correct, then please remove the smarty tag. Next; what exactly do you mean with duplicating index.php? Can you give a brief example of the code you mean to duplicate?

Comment: please post some example code so we can show you a counter example of the same code.

Comment: Okay, will do and no im not using smarty template, im going to remove the tag now

Comment: Thank you Azzyh. I think Mike's answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347833/php-sorting-out-in-a-smart-coding-way/2347909#2347909 sums it up pretty good. No need to copy index.php.

Comment: Yes that was great, although i dont know what to do if i want to ORDER BY id in the $sql line.. if i do that, then the sorting wont work, because then ORDER BY comes before "WHERE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without seeing example code, I can tell you this is an example of what I'd do.

```
<?
//all of the code before the SQL statement here...
$sql= ' SELECT `column` from `tablename`'; //or any other SQL that is appropriate before the conditional
if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
    if($_GET['sort'] == 'video'){
        $sql .= ' WHERE `SCtry` = 0';
    }elseif($_GET['sort'] == 'SCtry'){
        $sql .= ' WHERE `SCtry` = 1';
    }
}
$sql .= ' ORDER BY `whatever`'; //or any other SQL that is appropriate after the conditional
//rest of code... no need for duplication
?>
```

edited as per OP request...

Comment: This is good, exactly what i was asking for.. but how do i do, if i also have ORDER BY id ?

Comment: i would go for something like
    
    $sort_options = array("video" => " where `SCtry` = 0", ...);
    if( isset($sort_options[$_GET['sort']]) ) $sql .= $sort_option[$_GET['sort']];

but it would be much nicer to use something like doctrine or zend_db_table anyway

Comment: Roman, I agree. However, the nature of this question is so basic, I wanted to tailor the answer to code the OP could understand and use as is.